# Troubleshooting "UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES" within Intellij

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

So i've been working on learning Spark, Scala, and Hadoop. Im currently trying to get my Scala project to build but it's running into some SBT issues it seems.

This is my build.sbt:

```
name := "untitled2"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.5"

val sparkVersion = "2.3.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion
)
```

Console Result after trying to Refresh Project:

```
Error while importing sbt project:

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading settings from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jeanmac/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jeanmac/Downloads/untitled2/project
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to untitled2 (in build file:/Users/jeanmac/Downloads/untitled2/)
[info] sbt server started at local:///Users/jeanmac/.sbt/1.0/server/85e9f47a00bae4fc214a/sock
sbt:untitled2>
[info] Defining Global / sbtStructureOptions, Global / sbtStructureOutputFile, shellPrompt
[info] The new values will be used by no settings or tasks.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to untitled2 (in build file:/Users/jeanmac/Downloads/untitled2/)
[info] Applying State transformations org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks from /Users/jeanmac/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2017.3/Scala/launcher/sbt-structure-1.0.jar
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to untitled2 (in build file:/Users/jeanmac/Downloads/untitled2/)
[info] Updating ...
[warn]  module not found: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;2.3.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/jeanmac/.ivy2/local/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.12/2.3.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.12/2.3.0/spark-core_2.12-2.3.0.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /Users/jeanmac/.sbt/preloaded/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.12/2.3.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////Users/jeanmac/.sbt/preloaded/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.12/2.3.0/spark-core_2.12-2.3.0.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;2.3.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:2.3.0 (/Users/jeanmac/Downloads/untitled2/build.sbt#L9-12)
[warn]        +- default:untitled2_2.12:0.1
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;2.3.0: not found
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:331)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:205)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:243)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:204)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:199)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:196)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:242)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:190)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:46)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:99)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:112)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:112)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:95)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:126)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2383)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:39)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:66)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:262)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:271)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:262)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:174)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:36)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;2.3.0: not found
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:331)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:205)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:243)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:204)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:199)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:196)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:242)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:190)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:46)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:99)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:112)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:112)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:95)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:126)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2383)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:39)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:66)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:262)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:271)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:262)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:174)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:36)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;2.3.0: not found

[error] (ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;2.3.0: not found
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Mar 20, 2018 8:09:03 PM
[info] shutting down server
```

So I've been looking online for some help. Most of the results where based on how the `libraryDependencies` were written.

Here's more information about my current environment:

- OS X
- Java: java 9.0.4 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
- Scala: Scala 2.12.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 9.0.4).
- Spark: version 2.3.0 Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_162)
- Intellij

I currently do not know why my code can not build. I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a resolver that points to a repository that has these libraries. Add the following to your sbt:

```
resolvers  += "MavenRepository" at "http://central.maven.org/maven2"
```

UPDATE:

Looks like the spark team does not have a build for Scala 2.12 yet. In your build.sbt, your current scala target version is 2.12. Try changing it to a 2.11 version. Reference: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14220

Comment: when you say sbt, do you mean build.sbt or the actual sbt environment within terminal?

Comment: @JeanP in the build.sbt. Just put it above the `libraryDependencies`(you don't have to put it above, it just makes sense)

Comment: Alright, so i tried that. I received the same console result.

Comment: @JeanP I updated my answer. Looks like you need to use Scala 2.11 for now.

Comment: Alright, so that seemed to allow it to build. Thanks!

Comment: @JeanP The resolver is not the problem. It's the 2.12 version that causes trouble.